# How to Create a list with Missing Numbers in a non continious list of numbers using TCL

Tags: arrays, list, loops, tcl

I wanted to create a list of numbers with missing numbers in a given list as provided in the example below

Existing list  { 1,3, 5, 9 , 13, 15}

Resultant list  { 2,4,6,7,8,10,11,12,14}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extended TCL has the function `intersect3` which as one of its return values gives a list of `A-B`.  You could intersect your list with a list of all possible numbers that span your list.

If you don't use Extended TCL, you'll have to implement something yourself.

I hardly ever use TCL, so maybe there's a better way, but the basic approach is to just sort the list, then run through it and find the missing values:

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

set A {1 3 5 9 13 15}

set A [lsort -integer $A]
set B {}
set x 0
set y [lindex $A $x]

while {$x < [llength $A]} {
    set i [lindex $A $x]
    while {$y < $i} {
        lappend B $y
        incr y
    }
    incr x
    incr y
}
puts $B
```

Output:

```
2 4 6 7 8 10 11 12 14
```

Answer (score 1):

paddy's answer looks pretty good. This is a bit shorter, assumes the list is already sorted.

```
package require Tcl 8.5
set A {1 3 5 9 13 15}
set result [list]
for {set i [lindex $A 0]; incr i} {$i < [lindex $A end]} {incr i} {
    if {$i ni $A} {
        lappend result $i
    }
}
```

See http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/expr.htm#M15 for the "ni" operator.